# Problema con Pivot con query en Mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

tengo mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito convertirla en este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que realice fue algo como esto,
pero pienso que debe haber otra forma mejor, ademas que no entiendo porque me aparece un espacio en blanco en la segunda fila:

```
                SELECT  
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011'
                            THEN P.anno
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'ANO',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_01
                            THEN 'ENERO'
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'MES',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_01 = P.t_mes_01 
                            THEN P.t_mes_01 
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'VENTA_REAL'

                FROM    import_ventas_008 P

                UNION

                SELECT  
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011'
                            THEN P.anno
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'ANO',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_02
                            THEN 'FEBRERO'
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'MES',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_02 = P.t_mes_02 
                            THEN P.t_mes_02 
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'VENTA_REAL'

                FROM    import_ventas_008 P

                UNION

                SELECT  
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011'
                            THEN P.anno
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'ANO',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_03
                            THEN 'MARZO'
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'MES',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_03 = P.t_mes_03 
                            THEN P.t_mes_03 
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'VENTA_REAL'

                FROM    import_ventas_008 P

                UNION

                SELECT  
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011'
                            THEN P.anno
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'ANO',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_04
                            THEN 'ABRIL'
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'MES',
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN P.anno='2011' AND P.t_mes_04 = P.t_mes_04 
                            THEN P.t_mes_04 
                            ELSE NULL 
                        END
                    ) AS 'VENTA_REAL'

                FROM    import_ventas_008 P
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Tal vez buscas algo así? Y si espacio en blanco en la segunda fila

```
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-01-01') fecha,'Enero' mes_de_corte,t_mes_01 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-02-01') fecha,'Febrero' mes_de_corte,t_mes_02 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-03-01') fecha,'Marzo' mes_de_corte,t_mes_03 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-04-01') fecha,'Abril' mes_de_corte,t_mes_04 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-05-01') fecha,'Mayo' mes_de_corte,t_mes_05 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-06-01') fecha,'Junio' mes_de_corte,t_mes_06 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-07-01') fecha,'Julio' mes_de_corte,t_mes_07 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-08-01') fecha,'Agosto' mes_de_corte,t_mes_08 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-09-01') fecha,'Septiembre' mes_de_corte,t_mes_09 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-10-01') fecha,'Octubre' mes_de_corte,t_mes_10 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-11-01') fecha,'Noviembre' mes_de_corte,t_mes_11 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008 UNION
SELECT anno,CONCAT(anno,'-12-01') fecha,'Diciembre' mes_de_corte,t_mes_12 venta_real  FROM import_ventas_008;
```

Comment: Esta perfecto! Muchas Gracias. por casualidad tendrá algún contacto de gmal ?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi ficha con mis perfiles en LinkedIn y GitHub, contacta conmigo por https://www.linkedin.com/in/davidjpblanco/ y será un placer hablar contigo